# Response.Cookies.Append not appending the new value cookies C#

Tags: c#, cookies

Im currently using net core 6, and im testing whether the cookies is added

```
            CookieOptions myCookie = new CookieOptions()
                {
                    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10)
                };

            Response.Cookies.Append(AppConstant.SessionUserName, "testing", myCookie);
            Response.Cookies.Append("SessionToken", DateTime.Now.ToString(), myCookie);

            string? username = Request.Cookies[AppConstant.SessionUserName];
```

when i debug the Request.Cookies theres only 1 key and value,
.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.qBk9PxsqzGc

i don't really understand about cookie, can someone help me why my string username is always null? is there anything i should configure?

Answer (score 0):

The cookie won't be attached to your current request's CookieCollection,You could check the cookie in your next request's CookieCollection with your codes:

Also,you could check if the cookie has been attached as below:

Press F12 in your browser=>Application=>Cookies

A minimal example in a default MVC app:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("MyCookie", "CookieVal");
            var mycookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"];
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            var mycookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"];
            return View();
        }
```

When I debug:
[image]